# How to add a 2nd Y-axis on a grouped bar chart using Altair? and sort the bar using value of one of the column from the data

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to add a 3rd axis or 2nd Y-axis to the group chart. I'm not sure if it is possible. 
Ideally, I want to -
1) add a line to this chart, which represents the "percentage of Arrest" made for the given year and a crime type.
2) sort the bars with each group using a value of column "rank" from the data.

Here is my code and the current visualization. Your valuable feedback is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
import altair as alt

base = alt.Chart().encode(
    x=alt.X('primary_type',scale=alt.Scale(rangeStep=12),title=None,sort=alt.EncodingSortField(op='sum', field='rank')),
    color=alt.Color('primary_type:N')
    )

bar = base.mark_bar().encode(
alt.Y('sum(Number_of_Incidents):Q',title='Total Number of Incidents')
)
line =  base.mark_line(color='red').encode(
alt.Y('percent_arrest',
    axis=alt.Axis(title=None))
)

combined = alt.layer(bar, line, data=q13a)

combined.facet(
column=alt.Column('year')
  ).resolve_scale(x='independent'
).configure_view(
stroke='transparent'
)
```

[image]

Sample Data -

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<thead><tr><th title="Field #1">year</th>
<th title="Field #2">primary_type</th>
<th title="Field #3">Number_of_Incidents</th>
<th title="Field #4">number_of_arrests</th>
<th title="Field #5">percent_arrest</th>
<th title="Field #6">rank</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td align="right">2018</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">57330</td>
<td align="right">5503</td>
<td align="right">9.6</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2018</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">44667</td>
<td align="right">8886</td>
<td align="right">19.89</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2018</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">24889</td>
<td align="right">1498</td>
<td align="right">6.02</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2018</td>
<td>ASSAULT</td>
<td align="right">18229</td>
<td align="right">2931</td>
<td align="right">16.08</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2018</td>
<td>DECEPTIVE PRACTICE</td>
<td align="right">15879</td>
<td align="right">713</td>
<td align="right">4.49</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2017</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">64334</td>
<td align="right">6459</td>
<td align="right">10.04</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2017</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">49213</td>
<td align="right">10060</td>
<td align="right">20.44</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2017</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">29040</td>
<td align="right">1747</td>
<td align="right">6.02</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2017</td>
<td>ASSAULT</td>
<td align="right">19298</td>
<td align="right">3455</td>
<td align="right">17.9</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2017</td>
<td>DECEPTIVE PRACTICE</td>
<td align="right">18816</td>
<td align="right">805</td>
<td align="right">4.28</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2016</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">61600</td>
<td align="right">6518</td>
<td align="right">10.58</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2016</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">50292</td>
<td align="right">10328</td>
<td align="right">20.54</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2016</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">31018</td>
<td align="right">1668</td>
<td align="right">5.38</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2016</td>
<td>ASSAULT</td>
<td align="right">18738</td>
<td align="right">3490</td>
<td align="right">18.63</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2016</td>
<td>DECEPTIVE PRACTICE</td>
<td align="right">18733</td>
<td align="right">815</td>
<td align="right">4.35</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">57335</td>
<td align="right">6771</td>
<td align="right">11.81</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">48918</td>
<td align="right">11558</td>
<td align="right">23.63</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">28675</td>
<td align="right">1835</td>
<td align="right">6.4</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">23883</td>
<td align="right">23875</td>
<td align="right">99.97</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2015</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">17552</td>
<td align="right">4795</td>
<td align="right">27.32</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2014</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">61561</td>
<td align="right">7415</td>
<td align="right">12.04</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2014</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">49447</td>
<td align="right">12517</td>
<td align="right">25.31</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2014</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">29116</td>
<td align="right">29000</td>
<td align="right">99.6</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2014</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">27798</td>
<td align="right">2095</td>
<td align="right">7.54</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2014</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">16979</td>
<td align="right">4159</td>
<td align="right">24.49</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2013</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">71530</td>
<td align="right">7727</td>
<td align="right">10.8</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2013</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">54002</td>
<td align="right">12927</td>
<td align="right">23.94</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2013</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">34127</td>
<td align="right">33819</td>
<td align="right">99.1</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2013</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">30853</td>
<td align="right">2107</td>
<td align="right">6.83</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2013</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">17993</td>
<td align="right">3400</td>
<td align="right">18.9</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2012</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">75460</td>
<td align="right">8249</td>
<td align="right">10.93</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2012</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">59135</td>
<td align="right">13061</td>
<td align="right">22.09</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2012</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">35854</td>
<td align="right">2462</td>
<td align="right">6.87</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2012</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">35488</td>
<td align="right">35226</td>
<td align="right">99.26</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2012</td>
<td>BURGLARY</td>
<td align="right">22843</td>
<td align="right">1285</td>
<td align="right">5.63</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2011</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">75148</td>
<td align="right">8468</td>
<td align="right">11.27</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2011</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">60458</td>
<td align="right">14139</td>
<td align="right">23.39</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2011</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">38605</td>
<td align="right">38544</td>
<td align="right">99.84</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2011</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">37332</td>
<td align="right">2583</td>
<td align="right">6.92</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2011</td>
<td>BURGLARY</td>
<td align="right">26619</td>
<td align="right">1272</td>
<td align="right">4.78</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2010</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">76754</td>
<td align="right">7844</td>
<td align="right">10.22</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2010</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">65403</td>
<td align="right">14277</td>
<td align="right">21.83</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2010</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">43393</td>
<td align="right">43294</td>
<td align="right">99.77</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2010</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">40653</td>
<td align="right">2641</td>
<td align="right">6.5</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2010</td>
<td>BURGLARY</td>
<td align="right">26422</td>
<td align="right">1382</td>
<td align="right">5.23</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2009</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">80973</td>
<td align="right">9900</td>
<td align="right">12.23</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2009</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">68462</td>
<td align="right">16325</td>
<td align="right">23.85</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2009</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">47724</td>
<td align="right">3270</td>
<td align="right">6.85</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2009</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">43543</td>
<td align="right">43193</td>
<td align="right">99.2</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2009</td>
<td>BURGLARY</td>
<td align="right">26766</td>
<td align="right">1412</td>
<td align="right">5.28</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2008</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">88433</td>
<td align="right">9291</td>
<td align="right">10.51</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2008</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">75922</td>
<td align="right">15520</td>
<td align="right">20.44</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2008</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">52841</td>
<td align="right">3403</td>
<td align="right">6.44</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2008</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">46507</td>
<td align="right">45459</td>
<td align="right">97.75</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2008</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">26533</td>
<td align="right">3496</td>
<td align="right">13.18</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2007</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">85156</td>
<td align="right">9783</td>
<td align="right">11.49</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2007</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">79591</td>
<td align="right">19386</td>
<td align="right">24.36</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2007</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">54454</td>
<td align="right">53251</td>
<td align="right">97.79</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2007</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">53749</td>
<td align="right">3994</td>
<td align="right">7.43</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2007</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">26863</td>
<td align="right">4230</td>
<td align="right">15.75</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2006</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">86240</td>
<td align="right">10108</td>
<td align="right">11.72</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2006</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">80666</td>
<td align="right">18892</td>
<td align="right">23.42</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2006</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">57124</td>
<td align="right">4135</td>
<td align="right">7.24</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2006</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">55813</td>
<td align="right">55236</td>
<td align="right">98.97</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2006</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">27100</td>
<td align="right">4010</td>
<td align="right">14.8</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2005</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">85685</td>
<td align="right">11338</td>
<td align="right">13.23</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2005</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">83965</td>
<td align="right">19994</td>
<td align="right">23.81</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2005</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">56234</td>
<td align="right">56121</td>
<td align="right">99.8</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2005</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">54548</td>
<td align="right">4083</td>
<td align="right">7.49</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2005</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">28028</td>
<td align="right">4726</td>
<td align="right">16.86</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2004</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">95463</td>
<td align="right">12068</td>
<td align="right">12.64</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2004</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">87136</td>
<td align="right">20718</td>
<td align="right">23.78</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2004</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">57060</td>
<td align="right">57034</td>
<td align="right">99.95</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2004</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">53164</td>
<td align="right">3965</td>
<td align="right">7.46</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2004</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">29532</td>
<td align="right">5386</td>
<td align="right">18.24</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2003</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">98875</td>
<td align="right">12889</td>
<td align="right">13.04</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2003</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">88378</td>
<td align="right">20459</td>
<td align="right">23.15</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2003</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">55011</td>
<td align="right">4060</td>
<td align="right">7.38</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2003</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">54288</td>
<td align="right">54283</td>
<td align="right">99.99</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2003</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">31147</td>
<td align="right">5856</td>
<td align="right">18.8</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2002</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">98327</td>
<td align="right">13697</td>
<td align="right">13.93</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2002</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">94153</td>
<td align="right">21331</td>
<td align="right">22.66</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2002</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">55940</td>
<td align="right">4403</td>
<td align="right">7.87</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2002</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">51789</td>
<td align="right">51781</td>
<td align="right">99.98</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2002</td>
<td>OTHER OFFENSE</td>
<td align="right">32599</td>
<td align="right">5701</td>
<td align="right">17.49</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2001</td>
<td>THEFT</td>
<td align="right">99264</td>
<td align="right">15543</td>
<td align="right">15.66</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2001</td>
<td>BATTERY</td>
<td align="right">93447</td>
<td align="right">20463</td>
<td align="right">21.9</td>
<td align="right">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2001</td>
<td>CRIMINAL DAMAGE</td>
<td align="right">55851</td>
<td align="right">4548</td>
<td align="right">8.14</td>
<td align="right">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2001</td>
<td>NARCOTICS</td>
<td align="right">50567</td>
<td align="right">50559</td>
<td align="right">99.98</td>
<td align="right">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">2001</td>
<td>ASSAULT</td>
<td align="right">31384</td>
<td align="right">7150</td>
<td align="right">22.78</td>
<td align="right">5</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: @jakevdp - your feedback is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @FlorianGD - your feedback is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you have the data in CSV or other easily readable format?

Comment: I can't test the idea, because I'm not going to build a custom HTML parser to access your data, but from reading your code I suspect the issue is that you're including the color encoding in your line plot, so you end up with a bunch of lines containing a single point each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that, as far as I know, you cannot draw lines across charts. When creating a grouped bar chart, you have to facet across a column of your data. In effect, this produces several charts that are horizontally concatenated. So, for each chart you have only one point (for each color). If you want to have a line across years, you have to define your x axis to be years, and not facet it, and plot it separately. I would suggest vertical concatenation, to have the lines below the bars.

Note that I have taken the data from your previous question ([How to create a nested Grouped Bar Chart using Altair? - Added sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517044/how-to-create-a-nested-grouped-bar-chart-using-altair-added-sample-data)) because the way you provided it is not practical and I already had this one.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

q13a = pd.read_table(StringIO("""year   primary_type    Number_of_Incidents number_of_arrests   percent_arrest  rank
2018    THEFT   57330   5503    9.6     1
2018    BATTERY     44667   8886    19.89   2
2018    CRIMINAL DAMAGE     24889   1498    6.02    3
2018    ASSAULT     18229   2931    16.08   4
2018    DECEPTIVE PRACTICE  15879   713     4.49    5
2017    THEFT   64334   6459    10.04   1
2017    BATTERY     49213   10060   20.44   2
2017    CRIMINAL DAMAGE     29040   1747    6.02    3
2017    ASSAULT     19298   3455    17.9    4
2017    DECEPTIVE PRACTICE  18816   805     4.28    5
2016    THEFT   61600   6518    10.58   1
2016    BATTERY     50292   10328   20.54   2
2016    CRIMINAL DAMAGE     31018   1668    5.38    3
2016    ASSAULT     18738   3490    18.63   4
2016    DECEPTIVE PRACTICE  18733   815     4.35    5
2015    THEFT   57335   6771    11.81   1
2015    BATTERY     48918   11558   23.63   2
2015    CRIMINAL DAMAGE     28675   1835    6.4     3
2015    NARCOTICS   23883   23875   99.97   4
2015    OTHER OFFENSE   17552   4795    27.32   5
2014    THEFT   61561   7415    12.04   1
2014    BATTERY     49447   12517   25.31   2
2014    NARCOTICS   29116   29000   99.6    3
2014    CRIMINAL DAMAGE     27798   2095    7.54    4
2014    OTHER OFFENSE   16979   4159    24.49   5
2013    THEFT   71530   7727    10.8    1
2013    BATTERY     54002   12927   23.94   2
2013    NARCOTICS   34127   33819   99.1    3
2013    CRIMINAL DAMAGE     30853   2107    6.83    4
2013    OTHER OFFENSE   17993   3400    18.9    5"""))

bar = alt.Chart(height=200, width=100).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('primary_type:N',
            axis=None,
            title=None,
            sort=alt.EncodingSortField(op='sum', field='rank')),
    y=alt.Y('sum(Number_of_Incidents):Q',
          title='Total Number of Incidents'),
    color=alt.Color('primary_type:N')
).facet(
    column=alt.Column('year:O')
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent'
)

line = alt.Chart().mark_line(point=True, color='red').encode(
    x=alt.X('year:O', axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=0)),
    y=alt.Y('percent_arrest:Q'),
    color=alt.Color('primary_type:N', legend=None)
).properties(height=80, width=680)

alt.vconcat(bar, line, data=q13a).configure_view(stroke='transparent')
```

[image: altair-grouped-bar-chart-line-chart-below]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-29 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)</sup>