# How to make a grouped multibar time series chart in altair with DATE on the bottom and Column labels in a legend or popup?

Tags: python, altair

For example you might want data like:

```
DATE,KEY,VALUE
2019-01-01,REVENUE,100
2019-01-01,COST,100.1
...
```

plotted as a time series BAR chart with little space in between the bars and no labels except for dates. The popup or legend would show you what the REV,COST cols were.

Basic bar chart with alt.Column, alt.X, alt.Y works but the labels and grouping are wrong. Is it possible to make the Column groups correspond to the x-axis and hide the X axis labels?

EDIT:

Latest best:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
m = 100
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='D', periods=m),
    'REVENUE': np.random.randn(m),
    'COST': np.random.randn(m),
}).melt('DATE', var_name='KEY', value_name='VALUE')

bars = alt.Chart(data, width=10).mark_bar().encode(
    y=alt.Y('VALUE:Q', title=None),
    x=alt.X('KEY:O', axis=None),
    color=alt.Color('KEY:O', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category20')),
    tooltip=['DATE', 'KEY', 'VALUE'],
)

(bars).facet(
    column=alt.Column(
        'yearmonthdate(DATE):T', header=alt.Header(labelOrient="bottom",
                                                   labelAngle=-45,
                                                   format='%b %d %Y'
                                                  )
        ),
    align="none",
    spacing=0,
).configure_header(
    title=None
).configure_axis(
    grid=False
).configure_view(
    strokeOpacity=0
)
```

[image: update]

---

Another post because I can't seem to add multiple images to the original one.

This is another way with another flaw: the bars are overlapping. Notice the dates however are handled properly because this is using an actual axis.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = 250
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='D', periods=m),
    'REVENUE': np.random.randn(m),
    'COST': np.random.randn(m),
}).melt('DATE', var_name='KEY', value_name='VALUE')

# Create a selection that chooses the nearest point & selects based on x-value
nearest = alt.selection(type='single', nearest=True, on='mouseover',
                        fields=['REVENUE'], empty='none')

# The basic line
line = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar(interpolate='basis').encode(
    x='DATE:T',
    y='VALUE:Q',
    color='KEY:N'
).configure_bar(opacity=0.5)

line
```

[image]

Comment: This: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/grouped-bar-chart seems to be the ticket. But is maybe not supported in vega-lite.

Comment: Overall this feels like the wrong way of using this if the date range axis works so well with standard bar charts. The only downside with the standard bar chart is overlap of bars in not handled AFAIK ... there is no way to have bar series non overlapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a grouped bar chart using a combination of encodings and facets, and you can adjust the axis titles and scales to customize the appearance. Here is an examle (replicating https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/grouped-bar-chart in Altair, as you mentioned in your comment):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([
    {"category":"A", "position":0, "value":0.1},
    {"category":"A", "position":1, "value":0.6},
    {"category":"A", "position":2, "value":0.9},
    {"category":"A", "position":3, "value":0.4},
    {"category":"B", "position":0, "value":0.7},
    {"category":"B", "position":1, "value":0.2},
    {"category":"B", "position":2, "value":1.1},
    {"category":"B", "position":3, "value":0.8},
    {"category":"C", "position":0, "value":0.6},
    {"category":"C", "position":1, "value":0.1},
    {"category":"C", "position":2, "value":0.2},
    {"category":"C", "position":3, "value":0.7}
])

text = alt.Chart(data).mark_text(dx=-10, color='white').encode(
    x=alt.X('value:Q', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('position:O', axis=None),
    text='value:Q'
)

bars = text.mark_bar().encode(
    color=alt.Color('position:O', legend=None, scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category20')),
)

(bars + text).facet(
    row='category:N'
).configure_header(
    title=None
)
```

[image]

---

*original answer:*

I had trouble parsing from your question exactly what you're trying to do (in the future please consider including a code snippet demonstrating what you've tried and pointing out why the result is not sufficient), but here is an example of a bar chart with data of this form, that has x axis labeled by only date, with a tooltip and legend showing the revenue and cost:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='D', periods=4),
    'REVENUE': [100, 200, 150, 50],
    'COST': [150, 125, 75, 80],
}).melt('DATE', var_name='KEY', value_name='VALUE')

alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='yearmonthdate(DATE):O',
    y='VALUE',
    color='KEY',
    tooltip=['KEY', 'VALUE'],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! Yeah, I got to this stage as well but have yet to figure out how to unstack the bars from altair itself.

Comment: This example is relevant too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517044/how-to-create-a-nested-grouped-bar-chart-using-altair-added-sample-data?rq=1

Comment: So this example is basically what I'm after: 

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/grouped-bar-chart

I suspect this is to do with lower level constructs that might not be exposed yet through Altair.

Comment: Have updated with my latest best version. Only thing left is to figure out if there is a tick label optimizer ... for example to put less dates on the x-axis when crowded. I suspect that is up to the renderer though.

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, it looks like altair.HeaderConfig does not have labelOverlap at the moment. Probably it does not work like an axis.